# How to register a URL or a site in CAS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, cas

I am working on a site that has already a working Single Sign on using CAS. I was told to apply this function for a new site. That is when I click on a button, it would sign me in automatically on that new site.

So, how to add a new site giving it a Single Sign on capability?

The language that I use is Asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your application in the back office of the CAS server : `https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Services+Management` and to protect your web site, you need to use the CAS client for .Net : `https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/.Net+Cas+Client`.

Comment: Hi, I tried to access this url https://localhost:8443/cas/services/ changing the localhost:8443 to my cas server url as mentioned in this page https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Services+Management. However, it says Unable to connect to localhost:8080. Do i miss something that it do not able me to connect on the Service managment?

Comment: The services back office is protected by the CAS itself on which you must log in. In your CAS server, there is a `cas.properties` file where you must define properly the url of your CAS server for authentication : cas.securityContext.serviceProperties.service=${server.prefix}/services/j_acegi_cas_security_check. Moreover, your user must be defined to have the role ROLE_ADMIN in the `deployerConfigContext.xml` file.